# Is it a bad idea to use custom binary data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Recently I made a program where I used a data type of the following form:

```
data MyType = Constructor1 | Constructor2 deriving Eq
```

Yes, this type is practically the same as `Bool` I just named it something different to make my code more readable. Later in the program I have function(s) of the form

```
myFunc input = if input == Constructor1 then --do something
    else --do something else
```

The reason I think that this could be a bad idea is that if it were interpreted just the way that it is, every time the program came across this branch it would have to run through the `==` function that it set up for `MyType` to get a `Bool` to pass to the `if_then_else_` function, whereas if I had just used `Bool` the necessity of the `==` function is eliminated which would speed up the process.

Should I replace all instances of `MyType` with instances of `Bool` or does ghc optimize the use of data types like these somehow?

Comment: No, it's not bad -- actually, that's a very good idea! Just use pattern matching: e.g. `case` instead of `if`, or as Daniel Wagner shows below.

Comment: Even if it were less efficient, you should profile before making an optimization like that. I'd be pretty surprised if it were a bottleneck (if it were an issue).

Comment: GHC does in fact optimize representations of ADTs. I'm not even sure how it wouldn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, don't replace this with `Bool`; instead replace your equality check with pattern matching.

```
myFunc Constructor1 = -- do something
myFunc Constructor2 = -- do something else
```

Answer (score 2):

A few alternatives to Daniel's approach (which is the best one, anyway).

- Use `case .. of`

  ```
  myFunc input = case input of
     Constructor1 -> ...
     Constructor2 -> ...
  ```
- Roll your custom `if` (Haskell excels at this!)

  ```
  -- define this helper once
  myIf :: MyType -> a -> a -> a
  myIf Constructor1 x1 _  = x1
  myIf Constructor2 _  x2 = x2

  -- use it as many times as needed
  myFunc input = myIf input
     (...) -- "then"/Constructor1 branch
     (...) -- "else"/Constructor2 branch
  ```